# Collagen: similarity of human to fish and meat amino acids

Tags: proteins

I am looking for a collagen supplement for my partner who has joint pain, bone pain, fatigue associated with ligaments, flaccid skin problems, and is just over 40. As she does not eat fish or meat, and also does not eat much at all, hence not enough to absorb the required amino acids required in the synthesis of collagen, I am considering a collagen supplement. The collagen should break down in the body, thus generating the twenty amino acids that make part of the three collagen stands, collagen making up the ligaments, and it should take three months to start generating the extracellular tissue of I understand correctly.

So, I would like to know, how similar are the twenty amino acids that make up the tendons in the human body to the ones found in fish and meat, and what needs to be eaten with these supplements, fish, or meat, for the amino acids contained in collagen to work their way through the body's cells and be reformulated into ligaments outside the cells. I assume supplements such as colvita won't be enough and I want to know what to take with the supplements and food.

Can someone name the names of the twenty amino acids found in human ligaments?

If this post is inappropriate here, then please post to biology stack exchange.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can easily Google the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a quick search on Wikipedia and found this hope it helps you out .

The 9 essential amino acids that cannot be made by the body and must come from food are phenylalanine . valine . threonine , tryptophan , methionine , leucine , isoleucine , lysine and histadine.

There are 6 other amino acids that are considered conditionally essential in the human diet which means there synthesis may be limited under special pathophysiologoical conditions they are arginine , cysteine , glycine , glutamine , proline , tyrosine.

There are 5 amino acids that are dispensable by humans meaning they can be synthesized by the body, they are alanine , aspartic acid , asparagine , glutamic acid , and serine.

Ref:Wikipedia/9essentialaminoacids

Comment: Thanks. So is this the complete lusty of amino acids that are synthesized by the body?

Comment: There are 11 non essential amino acids, these are synthesized by the body.